# Racket/Scribble dynamic pdf generation

Tags: pdf, dynamic, racket, scribble

Hello all I am trying to dynamically build pdf files based on switches in a global defines file.

In file global_defines.rkt i have

```
#lang racket/base

(provide (all-defined-out))

(define alpha #f)
(define beta #t)
(define gamma #f)
```

in file foo.scrbl

```
#lang scribble/base
@(require "../../pdf_gen/global_defines.rkt")

@title{Getting Started}

@if[(or alpha)
        @para{Test text}
        ""]

@if[(or beta)
        (begin
            @dynamic-require["bar.scrbl" 'doc]
            doc)
        ""]
```

and in file bar.scrbl

```
#lang scribble/base
@(require "../../../pdf_gen/global_defines.rkt")
@(provide (all-defined-out))

@title{BAR}

happy marbles
```

so with the switches as they are currently i would expect to get something similar to the following out

**Getting Started**

1.BAR

happy marbles

while there are definitly other ways i can do it i would prefer to stick with scribble as it makes formatting and everything much easier than the other methods i can come up with right now. My main concerns are keeping the switches in one place and being able to pick and choose the content that is triggered by the switches being active, as there is content that will be common between several of the documents but not all of them, and quite a bit of content that only belongs in one or 2 places.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Does your sample code not work for you? Or it works, but you're looking for another way to do it?

Comment: One tiny tip: In foo.scrbl you could use `when`, instead of `if` with the explicit `""` for the false branch. Why: Scribble will handle `(void)` as if it were `""`.

Comment: no the sample code i have doesn't work for me. most of the vartiations i have tried give me a runtime error or i don't get the text from the second file included in the output pdf. also thanks for reminding me about the when function it'll help make things cleaner when i get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this answer isn't as elegant as I'd like, it works.

Basically I think you're talking about conditional compilation. In C you'd use a macro for this. In Racket let's use a macro, too (a macro which is just as brain-dead simple as a C macro).

Also we need a macro because Scribble's `include-section` is syntax (not a function) and must appear at the top-level. As a result, you can't use it inside of an `if` or `when`.

Given that:

**define.rkt**

```
#lang racket/base

(provide (all-defined-out))

;; Macros to conditionally include literal text.
;; Each of these should return `text`,
;; or (void) for nothing
(define-syntax-rule (when-alpha text)
  text)
(define-syntax-rule (when-beta text)
  (void))

;; Macros to conditionally include a .scrbl file
;; Each of these should return include-section,
;; or (void) for nothing
(require scribble/base) ;for include-section
(define-syntax-rule (when-alpha/include mod-path)
  (include-section mod-path))
(define-syntax-rule (when-beta/include mod-path)
  (void) #;(include-section mod-path))
```

Currently, this is set to show things for "alpha" but omit them for "beta". Unfortunately there's not a simple `#t` or `#f` to toggle. You need to edit the body of each one a bit more than that, as explained in the comments.

**manual.scrbl** example file conditionally including text and another file

```
#lang scribble/base
@(require "defines.rkt")
@title{Getting Started}
@when-alpha{@para{Text for alpha}}
@(when-beta/include "includee.scrbl")
```

**includee.scrbl** example file being conditionally included

```
#lang scribble/base
@title{BETA TEXT}
I am text for beta version.
```

What I don't love about this solution is that you have to create/change a *pair* of macros for each condition -- one for including literal text, and another for `include-section`-ing a .scrbl file.

Comment: it'll work like you said it's not exactly elegant and any or/and conditions are going to be a bit of a pain to setup for the includes but after the initial setup I can pretty easily write a brain dead script to write out the defines file for me. I probably wasn't clear enough the literal text works its just the text that has to be pulled from other files down stream that was the problem